# Как вызвать функцию по прокрутке дива до конца?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть шаблон [hey](http://mistxs.ru/hey), в котором анимация реализована через библиотеки `ScrollMagic` и `TweenMax`. 
Заказчик хочет сделать более плавную прокрутку, чтобы анимация при прокрутке дива до конца воспроизводилась сама, как это сделано в верхнем меню.

Я нашел в коде функцию которая отвечает за скролл в верхнем меню:

```
function scrollTo(event) {
   var target = $(this).attr('href').split('#');

   controller.scrollTo('#' + target[target.length - 1]);
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Как бы мне теперь ее видоизменить чтобы она вызывалась когда основной див секции заканчивался?

Comment: Можно слушать изменение координат div, например, как здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2712188/873481

Answer (score 1):

В ScrollMagic длительность анимации задается свойством duration. Например, в вашем коде:

```
var scene = new ScrollScene({
                    triggerElement: section,
                    triggerHook: 1,
                    duration: settings.height
                })
```

Если выставить duration: 0, анимация будет воспроизводится, когда сработает триггер triggerElement.

Чтобы увидеть метки триггеров, добавьте к каждой сцене .addIndicators(), пример:

```
var scene = new ScrollScene({
                        triggerElement: section,
                        triggerHook: 1,
                        duration: settings.height
                    })
                   .addIndicators()
```

И подключите скрипт http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js
Можете почитать про ScrollMagic на русском [ScrollMagic – Создание анимации при прокрутке страницы](http://www.creative-seo.ru/blog/scrollmagic-sozdanie-animacii-pri-prokrutke-stranicy/)